# FORM fields checking

Tags: forms, checkbox

I have a simple form with several checkboxes. Now I need to prevent users to proceed with this form if more then 3 checkboxes are selected. How should this be done?

Comment: are you using vanilla js or some sort of js framework (jQuer, Prototype, MooTools, Dojo, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Prevent the user from proceeding in what fashion?

On general way would be to simply keep track of the number of check boxes checked within your checkbox check methods.  In each check method, check your checkbox count variable and you can proceed from there how you want to prevent the user from interacting with your form.

Comment: Thanks, and do you now any other way to redirect the page in php except for header?

Comment: I'm sorry, I am not very familiar with php :(